# Git Public Key Access denied

Tags: git, windows-7-x64

I setup today Git on my Windows 7 64bit Machine. I used the git bash for setting up the public key etc. and copied the information also to my account as proposed in [Github help](http://help.github.com/win-set-up-git/).

Now I want to use git within the cmd of my windows machine instead of the git bash. If I now type `ssh -vT git@github.com` I get the following results:

CMD:

```
OpenSSH_4.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8e 23 Feb 2007
debug1: Connecting to github.com [207.97.227.239] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_dsa type -1
...
```

GIT Bash:

```
OpenSSH_4.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8e 23 Feb 2007
debug1: Connecting to github.com [207.97.227.239] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Mark/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Mark/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Mark/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
```

On the cmd git is aborting with the error message: Permission denied (publickey). Just to let you know I already copied the public key to github.
In the git bash its working.

The strange thing is on my notebook Windows 7 but 32 bit its working. Any clue about this issue?

Comment: What's the output on your notebook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run the following from cmd and try the ssh again:

```
set HOME=c:\Users\Mark
```

Comment: That did the trick, did i missed something for the configuration? Or is it related to my windows version?