# Permission Denied Error observed when running git clone command from cmd

Tags: git, bash, cmd

I am using Windows 7. When I am cloning repository from git bash i am able to clone but when i am trying to do the same from cmd i am observing following

```
error:Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Git path is set in env variable and able to execute git commands on cmd

```
C:\Users\mays>git
usage: git [--version] [--help] [-C <path>] [-c name=value]
           [--exec-path[=<path>]] [--html-path] [--man-path] [--info-path]
           [-p|--paginate|--no-pager] [--no-replace-objects] [--bare]
           [--git-dir=<path>] [--work-tree=<path>] [--namespace=<name>]
```

As i'm trying to some automation i need this.Can somebody help me here.             []

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey/

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/7379051/7976758

Comment: Both methods i have tried both it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you using `ssh` or `http`? If you are using `ssh` are you sure you have it configured correctly on your machine and stored the public key at the hosting platform and the url is correct and not indicating a different user or key?

Comment: This is fixed now.Thank You all for the suggestions. It was the problem with Windows File System.